# C# Regex Matches to return next matches that start from second character from previous match

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to make Regex.Matches such that the next match will start with the second character from the previous match of the matched group. The default behavior is that the new match starts after the end of previous match.
As an example,

```
string s = "abc123456789xyz";
Regex.Matches(s, @".*?(\d{4}).*?")
```

Returns only two matches:
    1234,5678

I'd like it to return:

```
1234,2345,3456,4567,5678,6789
```

Comment: What about `(?=(\d{4}))`?

Comment: Thank you @ctwheels, that worked! I guess I have to brush up my knowledge on lookahead/lookbehind constructs.